# Error C2679: binary '=' : no operator

Tags: c++

I'm coding a file loader/editor and I have a problem like this: `C2679: binary '=' : no operator found`, which takes a right-hand operand of type `std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>` (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
    std::string szName;
    szName = "";
    ReadFile(hFile, &nL, 4, &dwRWC, NULL);

    if(nL > 0)
    {
        std::vector<char> buffer(nL+1, NULL);
        ReadFile(hFile, &buffer.begin(), nL, &dwRWC, NULL);
        szName = buffer.begin(); //problem is here
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Since you are setting `szName=""`, am I right to assume the variable is a string? If you want to get the buffer and assign it to a string, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115166/how-to-construct-a-stdstring-from-a-stdvectorchar). The problem, as mentioned by CoryKramer, is that you are trying to assign an iterator to a variable that is not iterator.

Comment: Hungarian notation needs to die a very painful death.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys Cory Kramer solved my problem with this -> "szName = *(buffer.begin());" :)

Comment: Really? I doubt it, since that would result in a type mismatch.

Comment: There is still something wrong even with the answer accepted. `*(buffer.begin())` is (convertible to) a `char &`. If `szName` is a `char *` the accept solution is an assignedment of a pointer to from a `char`, which should throw warnings all over. If `szName` is a `char`, `szName = ""` is a narrowing conversion that is not acceptable at all. Why isn't the type of `szName` part of the question by now?

Comment: szName isn't a char its a string

Comment: @RepahidiS Please edit your question to reflect this information.

Comment: When you say it's a string, do you mean std::string?

Comment: @dhke okey I'm editing now.

Comment: @JPhi1618 yes std::string szName;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`begin` will return an iterator, which you are trying to assign to a `char`. Either dereference the iterator

```
szName = *(buffer.begin());
```

or just call `front`

```
szName = buffer.front();
```

**Edit**

If `szName` is **not** a `char` and is instead a `std::string`, you should actually do something like the following to construct a `std::string`

```
szName = std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
```

Comment: Thank you so much its worked! :)

Comment: Would be nice to remind him that, if `szName` is a string and not a char, he will be assigning only the first char of the vector. Im pointing this out because in his snippet, he used `szName=""` and not `szName=' '`.

Comment: Is it a `char`? Doesn't look that way to me.

Comment: szName is a string guys not a char

Comment: Can you update this answer to reflect that `szName` is an `std::string`, and indicate that the assignment actually calls [`operator=(char c)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/`)? As it stands this answer is wrong in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this code is wrong:

```
ReadFile(hFile, &buffer.begin(), nL, &dwRWC, NULL);
```

you are trying to read into iterator itself, not `std::vector` data. This actually should not compile as you taking address of temporary which is not lvalue, but most probably compiles because of "friendly" MS extension, that allows temporary to lvalue conversion. So anyway code should be:

```
ReadFile(hFile, &buffer[0], nL, &dwRWC, NULL);
```

Assignment to string could be:

```
message = std::string( buffer.begin(), buffer.end() );
```